How to manage imports of different DLLs across multiple platforms in C#?
I'm working on a C# project that needs to support different DLLs on Windows and Linux. I need to load the appropriate .dll/.so depending on the platform where the application is running.
private static class Imports
{
     private const string DllName = "pdfium.dll"; // or "pdfium_x64.so"
     private const CharSet PdfiumCharSet = CharSet.Ansi;
     private const CallingConvention PdfiumCallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall;

     [DllImport(DllName)]
     public static extern void FPDF_InitLibrary();

     [DllImport(DllName)]
     public static extern void FPDF_DestroyLibrary();

     [DllImport(DllName, CallingConvention = PdfiumCallingConvention, CharSet = PdfiumCharSet)]
     public static extern DocumentHandle FPDF_LoadMemDocument(IntPtr buffer, int size, string password);

     ...
}

I considered using preprocessor directives, but I encountered a problem with the availability of methods in other classes. I also considered using a SOLID patterns to create an abstraction layer for accessing DLL functions, which would allow for flexible management of different implementations(both cases seem to fail when using imported functions).
Are there other methods that might be effective in this situation? What are the recommended practices for managing DLL dependencies across different system platforms in .NET?

"I considered using preprocessor directives, but I encountered a problem with the availability of methods in other classes." - What does that mean? If I had to do that, I'd do exactly that: Have conditional compilation sections and build for the respective platform. You'll end up with a platform-specific artifacts, though. Is that against your requirements?

in .Net 6+ it is possible to use SetDllImportResolver. Take a look at charls native for a real world example.

I mixed up the names in the condition statements in preprocessor directives, thanks for the help guys
